# how to extract the data without a class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to extract the data without a class using jQuery?

```
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="27%" valign="top" align="right"> <font size="2"></font>

        </td>
        <td width="73%" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="27%" valign="top" align="right"> <font size="2">Company Name :</font>

        </td>
        <td width="73%" valign="top">
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td width="27%" valign="top" align="right">    <font size="2">Web Site Link :</font>

         </td>
         <td width="73%" valign="top">  <font size="2">http://www.comde.com.my</font>

         </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the output like this...
Ex:
companyname:xxx

website:www.gmail.com

Comment: First of all you need to fix the markup. I don't think that jQuery will be able to parse this mess.

Comment: Even for dummy examples do not use font tag its deprecated now

Comment: See--> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4PB6J/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rows = [];

$('table tr').each(function() {

    var cells = [];

    $(this).find('td').each(function() {

        cells.push($.trim($(this).text()));
    });

    var cline = $.trim(cells.join(' '));

    if (cline)
        rows.push(cline);
});

console.log(rows);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R4Tr8/